# Run Python script in Vagrant

Tags: python, ssh, virtual-machine, vagrant, vagrantfile

This is a dumb question but please help me.

Q. How do I run Python script that is saved in my local machine?

after `vagrant up` and `vagrant ssh`, I do not see any Python file in the VM. Then what if I want to run Python scripts that are saved in my Mac? I do not want to copy and paste them manually using vim.

How would you run Python script in Vagrant ssh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your Guest OS there will be a folder under `/` called `/vagrant/` this will be all the files and directories under the directory on your `host` machine that contains the `.VagrantFile`

If you put your script in that folder they will be shared with the VM.

Additionally if you are using `chef` as your provisioner you can use a `script` resource to run external scripts during the provisioning step.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. You can go the classic route of using the shell provisioner using vagrant

   config.vm.provision "shell", inline: $script

And in your script run the python script

2. All files are pushed in /tmp, you can possible use this to run your python script