# Run a Python script in Vagrant

Tags: python, bash, vagrant

I'm learning how to use Vagrant with a Udacity course, and we're asked to run a Python script `database_setup.py` in our virtual machine.

For this, I created a folder "udacityproject" inside my vagrant folder on my computer. I saved my file `database_setup.py` there.

Now on Bash, I do

```
$ vagrant up
$ vagrant ssh
$ cd udacityproject 
$ python database_setup.py
```

The interface returns:

> "python: can't open file 'database_setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file
>   or directory".

It must be a silly mistake, but I cannot see what I am doing wrong... A similar topic was opened here ([Run Python script in Vagrant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23232172/run-python-script-in-vagrant)) but the answers are not helping me.

Comment: Is the file executable? run `ls -l` and check the permissions on this file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725273/python-oserror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `vagrant` folder on your computer, which contains the file `VagrantFile`, is the folder **`/vagrant`** on your vm *(It is under **`/`**)*. It's not your home directory. After `vagrant ssh` you are logged in home directory of user vagrant. It's `/home/vagrant/`.

```
$ vagrant ssh
$ pwd
/home/vagrant
```

The tree looks like that:

```
/root
/tmp
/usr
/var
/home
     |-- vagrant  # <-- You are here after logging
/vagrant
        |-- udacityproject
                         |-- database_setup.py  # <-- Your script is here
...
```

To run your script you must go to `/vagrant`

```
$ cd /vagrant
```

With `ls *` you can check if your file exists. Now go to your created folder and run your script

```
$ cd udacityproject
$ python database_setup.py
```

Or simply do that from beginning:

```
$ vagrant ssh
$ python /vagrant/udacityproject/database_setup.py
```